# Saving HTML To MySQL Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting error message saying "0 rows affected.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'content' at row 1" when i am saving my html to Mysql database.

The Html is as under:

About Us

```
    <p>We are revolutionising the way people shop around the world by providing the freedom to purchase from any website using your very own US or UK shipping address. We're used by both consumers and businesses to buy all sorts of products and merchandise from overseas. Have a look at what people are <a href="/pages/testimonials">saying</a> about us.</p>
    <h2 class="title" id="title"> We<span class="green"> Offer</span> </h2>
    <ul class="arr">
      <li>Great deals from all over the globe on a range of products from the hottest fashion to the latest technology.</li>
      <li>Shipping rates designed with the consumer in mind!</li>
      <li>Social Shipping- buy with friends and create one large package for Big Savings!</li>
      <li>A clever Total Cost Calculator that allows you to see the Total Cost to deliver your package to your door- duties and taxes included!</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="title" id="title"> So who are<span class="green"> We</span> </h2>
    <ul class="arr">
      <li><a href="/bx/enUS/pages/the-team">Check-out our team's profiles.</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="title" id="title"> Who uses <span class="green"> Store to Ship?</span> </h2>
    <p>Store to Ship is used by private consumers and businesses to buy all sorts of products and merchandise overseas. Have a look at what people are saying about us.</p>
```

Comment: Please share the code that inserts your html into the database.

Comment: Can you please post your table structure too?

Comment: Could be interresting to see your table structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Warning Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736373/mysql-warning-question)

Comment: what is the database field type for the html ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data truncated for column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089240/data-truncated-for-column)

Comment: Use `LONGTEXT` for HTML fields.

Comment: structure for table `menu`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `menu_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

Comment: Post the code to your question, well formatted, where it belongs to, not as a comment...

Comment: I am doing it manually just copy paste :)

Answer (score 6):

It's because the length of the value you are inserting is greater than the length defined on the column. Increase the length of your column.

Comment: What should b the exact lenght?/

Comment: If you're not aware about approximate length. Use Type as TEXT

Answer (score 1):

I hope following explanation will help you

```
1. Use LONGTEXT/TEXT as type for the field in which you want to save html data
2.
   <?php
     $data = "HTML data";

     if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
         $data = trim($data);
     else 
         $data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);
   ?>
3. then insert to this field.
```

Comment: Thank you all for Your Nice Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text DataType` to store your HTML code in it.

Your length of data is greater than the defined length .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, menu_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, menu_url varchar(255) NOT NULL, content TEXT() NOT NULL, image varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```